# Zend framework 2, hierarchical routes, JSon Return

Tags: php, json, rest, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am new to zend framework. I have gone thought the tutorials and have a working url but it does not works the way I need it to. 
I am using Zend Framework 2.4.

http://localhost/part/3
it returns all parts with id of 3 in json format (which is what I want)

http://localhost/part/3/patents 
still only returns all parts with id of 3 in json format. What I want is to return all of the patents that are for part 3

First went down the path that different default actions would do it but it seem to not work do to the 'ViewJsonStrategy' you can not set a default action to my knowledge. Have also try onBootstrap() version of this post but cant get it to work.
[Zend_Rest_Route and hierarchical routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189987/zend-rest-route-and-hierarchical-routes) 
The Last Thing I tried which was a shot in the dark was creating another controller for patent didn't work.

So my question is are any of these the right paths and if so what am I doing wrong, if not then how can I? 
 Here is my  module.config.php

```
 return array(
     'controllers' => array(
         'invokables' => array(
        'Part\Controller\Part' => 'Part\Controller\PartController',
        'Part\Controller\Patent' =>'Part\Controller\PatentController'
    ),
),

// The following section is new` and should be added to your file
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'part' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/v1.0/part[/:id]', 
                'constraints' => array(
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Part\Controller\Part',
                   // 'action' => 'index'
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'patent' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/patent',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Part\Controller\part',
                        )

                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
   'view_manager' => array(
   'strategies' => array(
       'part' => 'ViewJsonStrategy',
      'patent' => 'ViewJsonStrategy',
    ),
),
);
```

Here is my Module.php

```
namespace Part;

use Part\Model\PartTable;
use Part\Model\Patent;

class Module
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
       return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
        ),
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}

public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Part\Model\PartTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $table = new PartTable($dbAdapter);
                return $table;
            },
             'Part\Model\Patent' =>  function($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $table = new \Patent($dbAdapter);
                return $table;
            },
        ),
    );
}    

public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}
}
```

Here is my PartController.php

```
namespace Part\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

class PartController extends AbstractRestfulController
{
protected $partTable;

public function getList()
{
    $results = $this->getPartTable()->fetchAll();
    $data = array();
    foreach($results as $result) {
        $data[] = $result;
    }

    return new JsonModel(array(
        'data' => $data,
    ));
}
public function get($id)
{
   $results = $this->getPartTable()->fetchById($id);
   $data = array();
    foreach($results as $result) {
        $data[] = $result;
    }

    return new JsonModel(array(
        'data' => $data,
    ));
}

public function create($data)
{

}

public function update($id, $data)
{

}

public function delete($id)
{

}
public function getPartTable()
{
    if (!$this->partTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->partTable= $sm->get('Part\Model\PartTable');
    }
    return $this->partTable;
}
}
```

Here is my PatentController.php

```
namespace Part\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

class PatentController extends AbstractRestfulController
{
protected $patent;

public function getList()
{
    $results = $this->getPatent()->fetchAllBooks();
    $data = array();
    foreach($results as $result) {
        $data[] = $result;
    }

    return new JsonModel(array(
        'data' => $data,
    ));
}
public function get($id)
{
   $results = $this->getPatent()->fetchById($id);
   $data = array();
    foreach($results as $result) {
        $data[] = $result;
    }

    return new JsonModel(array(
        'data' => $data,
    ));
}
public function getPatent()
{
    if (!$this->patent) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->patent= $sm->get('Part\Model\part');
    }
    return $this->partTable;
}
}
```

Here is my PartTable.php

```
  namespace Part\Model;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
class PartTable 
{


public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
{
    $this->adapter = $adapter;
}

public function fetchAll()
{
    $statement = $this->adapter->createStatement('SELECT * FROM test.album');
    $result = $statement->execute();
    return $result;

}
public function fetchById($id){
    $statement = $this->adapter->createStatement('SELECT * FROM test.album where id = '.$id);
    $result = $statement->execute();
    return $result;
}

}
```

Here is my Patent.php

```
namespace Patent\Model;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
class Patent
{

public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
{
    $this->adapter = $adapter;
}

public function fetchAll()
{
    $statement = $this->adapter->createStatement('SELECT * FROM test.book');
    $result = $statement->execute();
    return $result;

}
 public function fetchById($id){
    $statement = $this->adapter->createStatement('SELECT * FROM test.book where id = '.$id);
    $result = $statement->execute();
    return $result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the configuration. Instead of this:

```
'child_routes' => array(
                'patent' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/patent',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Part\Controller\part',
                        )

                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

you should have:

```
'child_routes' => array(
                'patent' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/patents',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Part\Controller\Patent',
                        )

                    ),
                ),
            ),
```